# float type-casting isn't working properly, always evaluates to 0.0

Tags: java, android, casting, floating-point, double

code:

```
double percentage = 0.7711627906976745;
mSweepAngle = (float)(360*(percentage/(double)100));
```

I've googled around and haven't found an answer, afaik I'm type-casting it correctly yet it keeps evaluating to 0.0. I've even tried typecasting `360`, `percentage` and `100` into float during the calculation but still it doesn't work...

**EDIT1:**
the full code:

```
package se.kiendys.petrus.da171a.uppg3.budgetapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class PieChartView extends View {

    private Paint piechartItem1Paint;
    private Paint piechartItem2Paint;
    private Paint piechartBorderPaint;
    private Paint infoBorderPaint;
    private Paint infoBackgroundPaint;
    private Paint infoTextPaint;
    private RectF oval;

    private int mWidth;
    private int mHeight;
    private int mMarginLeft;
    private int mMarginTop;
    private float mStartAngle;
    private float mSweepAngle;

    private double percentage;

    public PieChartView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public PieChartView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        piechartItem1Paint = new Paint();                   // the piechart items color
        piechartItem2Paint = new Paint();                   // the piechart items color
        piechartBorderPaint = new Paint();                  // the piechart border color
        infoTextPaint = new Paint();                        // the info text color
        infoBackgroundPaint = new Paint();                  // the info background color
        infoBorderPaint = new Paint();                      // the info border color

        mWidth = 200;       // circle width
        mHeight = 200;      // circle height
        mMarginLeft = 10;   // circle and info margin
        mMarginTop = 10;    // circle and info margin
        mStartAngle = 0;    // the starting angle of the arc, begins at the rightmost part of the circle (an angle of 0 degrees correspond to the geometric angle of 0 degrees, or 3 o'clock on a watch)
                            // and through incrementation moves clockwise, the units are degrees

        oval = new RectF(mMarginLeft, mMarginTop, mWidth, mHeight); // sets the shape and size (boundaries) of the drawn circle

        piechartItem1Paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        piechartItem1Paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        piechartItem1Paint.setStrokeWidth(0.5f);
        piechartItem2Paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        piechartItem2Paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        piechartItem2Paint.setStrokeWidth(0.5f);

        piechartItem1Paint.setColor(0xCCFEFEFE);    // blue color
        piechartItem2Paint.setColor(0xCC343434);    // green color

//      double temp = (360*((double)percentage/(double)100));
//      Log.d(BudgetConstants.DEBUG_TAG, "temp: "+temp);
//      mSweepAngle = (float)temp;
//      Log.d(BudgetConstants.DEBUG_TAG, "init mSweepAngle: "+mSweepAngle);
//      mSweepAngle = (float)(360*(percentage/(double)100));
//      mSweepAngle = (float)(percentage/100.0*360);
        Log.d(BudgetConstants.DEBUG_TAG, "init mSweepAngle: "+mSweepAngle);
    }

    public void setDistributionPercentage(double percentage) {
        this.percentage = percentage;
        Log.d(BudgetConstants.DEBUG_TAG, "percentage: "+percentage);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Log.d(BudgetConstants.DEBUG_TAG, "onDraw fired!");

        canvas.drawArc(oval, mStartAngle, mSweepAngle, true, piechartItem1Paint);
        Log.d(BudgetConstants.DEBUG_TAG, "startAngle1: "+mStartAngle+", sweepAngle1: "+mSweepAngle);
        canvas.drawArc(oval, mSweepAngle, (360-mSweepAngle), true, piechartItem2Paint);
        Log.d(BudgetConstants.DEBUG_TAG, "startAngle2: "+mSweepAngle+", sweepAngle2: "+(360-mSweepAngle));
    }

}
```

Please note that percentage is successfully passed from another activity, currently 0.7711627906976745 is being passed.

Comment: When I ran this (followed by `System.out.println(mSweepAngle);`) it gave me `2.776186`.  Are you sure there isn't a problem OTHER THAN this code?

Comment: In fact you do not need all of those castings. Since `percentage` is already a `double`, its division and multiplication return `double` values (the `int` are "converted" to `double` by the compiler). The issue you reference to is when you divide integers (v.g. `4/10` returning `0`)

Comment: Is it possible you have something like a field called `mSweepAngle` and also a local variable called `mSweepAngle` which is masking it?  Or maybe you're doing this calculation on one object, then checking the value on a different one?  Something like that?  Please show us ALL of your code, not just these two lines - these two lines are FINE.

Comment: Show a [self-contained compilable example](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Please check my EDIT, I added the full code.

Comment: Oh please. We don't need the entire GUI. Reduce it to an SCCE as @Eric suggested. You're just making it less and less likely that  anyone will even look at it.

Comment: No, this is fine.  You said that `percentage` was being set externally.  But how is that possible?  You're calling `init` from the constructor, and it's `init` that's doing this calculation.  Is it possible that `percentage` HASN'T been set at the time you're doing the calculation?

Comment: @DavidWallace that's probably the case! I'll check it out right away!

Comment: In the context of the whole program, is there a possible multi-threading issue? Could percentage be being set from a different thread than the one that displays the result? If so, is there a happens-before relationship?

Comment: @DavidWallace Ok, that was the issue, I tried to do initiations before getting the proper `percentage` value from `public void setDistributionPercentage(double percentage)`.
Do you wanna post an answer so I can approve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `init` from the constructor, and it's `init` that's doing this calculation. So no matter what mechanism you're using to set `percentage`, it's not happening till after the calculation has already been done.

I seriously recommend learning to use a debugger.  Stepping through your code would have told you immediately what was happening.